# The closest point from ellipse

Tags: geometry

The closest point of $a$ from the sphere $||x-x_0||= R$ we can give by this formula $$\frac{a-x_0}{||a-x_0||}\cdot R+x_0$$

How we can give such a formula to closest point of $a$ from this ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}=R^2$$

Comment: have you tried laplace multiplier method?

Comment: The $R$ should be 1 on the right side. As you give it, you have three parameters $A,B,R$ but only two are needed... since dividing both sides by $R^2$ and renaming $A,B$ covers all ellipses (alligned with $x,y$ axes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was advised, you need to use **Lagrange** multiplier method. Target function is distance $d$, or, even more convenient $d^2$:
$$
d^2 = \left( x-a_x\right)^2 + \left(y-a_y \right)^2
$$
Restriction is $\varphi(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}-R^2=0$, so
$$
L(x,y) = (x-a_x)^2+(y-a_y)^2-\lambda \left( \frac {x^2}{A^2} + \frac {y^2}{B^2}-R^2\right) \\
\frac {\partial L}{\partial x} = {2(x-a_x)} - \frac {2\lambda x}{A^2} = 0 \\
\frac {\partial L}{\partial y} = {2(y-a_y)} - \frac {2\lambda y}{A^2} = 0 \\
\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}-R^2=0
$$
If you try to solve it, you'll get
$$
x = \frac {a_x A^2}{A^2-\lambda} \\
y = \frac {a_y B^2}{B^2-\lambda}
$$
which you need to substitute into the ellipse equation. In general, that equation is quite nasty, so usually one uses different root finders.

You might be interested in this paper - [Distance from a Point to an Ellipse, an Ellipsoid, or a Hyperellipsoid](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePointEllipseEllipsoid.pdf)