# Quadratic Objective with Second Order Cone Constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, programming, second-order-cone-programming

is there any way to solve the following problem with a quadratic objective and a second-order cone constraint **in closed form**?

$$\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d} (x-x_0)^TA(x-x_0)
\\\text{subject to } \sqrt{x^T\Sigma x} + \mu^\top x\leq 0 $$

with $\Sigma$ and $A$ Positive Semi-Definite matrices and $x_0,\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution, but you can always write down the KKT conditions and try

Comment: Why don't you delete this question, when you have asked it [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3945748/minimizing-quadratic-objective-over-convex-set?noredirect=1) and with more detail and it was answered?

Comment: I realized that the solution provided was not enough, so I asked it again.

Comment: Please rather edit your previous question to reflect what you still need OR overhaul this question to include what you learnt from the answer and what you still want to know.